# An additional link in the person of apache2, for obtaining the https protocol

Tags: apache, http, https

The application works with a web browser over HTTP. How to get support
HTTPS protocol by placing apache2 web server between application and browser? thank.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, apache2 loaded the proxy and proxy_http modules.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

proxy has already been downloaded earlier. Added the directive to the site configuration file:

```
<Location /ZagotovkaCB>
        ProxyPass http://192.168.1.2:53572/ZagotovkaCB/
        ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.2:53572/ZagotovkaCB/
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location>
```

The local application runs on http through port number 53572 with a web browser.
To connect to the application by the browser, the following line was entered in the browser query line:

> http://192.168.1.2:53572/ZagotovkaCB

the virtual host runs on port 777 using the https protocol and enabling this
directive, it turned out now the link between apache2 and the web browser running on https and
the link between apache2 and the local application works as before through http.
Connection string now:

> https://192.168.1.2:777/ZagotovkaCB